# how to query in sqlite for different date format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using `sqlite` for local database in mobile and in my database, I have date field with column name `RN_CREATE_DATE`. My `RN_CREATE_DATE` column value is in this format `'dd-mm-yy  HH:MM:SS'` and I want to fetch data with given date. What will be the exact query for that I tried with below database column and value

**RN_CREATE_DATE

2012-07-27 11:04:34

2012-05-28 10:04:34
2012-07-22 09:04:34**

```
SELECT  RN_CREATE_DATE 
FROM DISPOSITION 
WHERE  RN_CREATE_DATE=strftime('%Y', '2012-07-28 12:04:34')
```

but no result found, just help me out with this.

Comment: See the documentation at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for the details for `strftime`.

Comment: I checked the documention and tried so many things with it...i am just confused how to put an exact query for this because in my database i am having diffrent date format and sqlite strftime function fetching diffrent one.

Comment: @vishalg maybe you want to update the question with detailed information, better with an example value of your database.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) works like this:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', datetime('now'));
2012-09-13 12:42:56
```

If you want to use it in a `WHERE` clause, replace `datetime('now')` with the datetime you want to match in the  `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format.

**Example:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE c = strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', '2012-09-13 12:44:22');
--                   dd-mm-YYYY HH:MM:SS  YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: One more query , this works for me but if i pass only date then it will not give any result why ..i don't want to include time   SELECT RN_CREATE_DATE
  FROM DISPOSITION
 WHERE RN_CREATE_DATE = strftime('%d-%m-%Y ', '2010-07-28');    i want all the records with this date

Comment: I don't quite understand either your answer or @vishalg 's question: if I store in the table a date without time: `insert into t values('item', date('2012-09-13 12:44:22')`, are you expect to select this item using the example above with the full date-time information?

Comment: The result shown above is WRONG:
"%d-%m-%Y" converts to "23-11-2023"  and not the year first as shown

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add some information about using SQLite Date and Time with UNIX epoch time:

The UNIX epoch was 00:00:00 1970-01-01, i.e. midnight of 1st Jan 1970. The current time on UNIX machines (like those running Linux) is measured in seconds since that time.

SQLite has support for this epoch time, and I've found it very useful for using it as the format for a DateTime field in SQLite.

Concretely, suppose I want to have an Event table, for events like concerts etc. I want a fromDateTime field to store when the event starts. I can do that by setting the fromDateTime filed to type INTEGER, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Event(
    eventID                     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name                        TEXT,
    ratingOutOf10               REAL,
    numberOfRatings             INTEGER,
    category                    TEXT,   
    venue                       TEXT,
    fromDateTime                INTEGER,
    description                 TEXT,   
    pricesList                  TEXT,   
    termsAndConditions          TEXT                
);
```

Now, let's get to the usage of the UNIX epoch with SQLite DateTime fields:

```
Basic
    select strftime('%s', '2016-01-01 00:10:11');               --returns 1451607012
    select datetime(1451607012, 'unixepoch');                   --returns 2016-01-01 00:10:11
    select datetime(1451607012, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');      --returns 2016-01-01 05:40:11 i.e. local time (in India, this is +5:30).

Only dates and/or times:
    select strftime('%s', '2016-01-01');                        --returns 1451606400
    select strftime('%s', '2016-01-01 16:00');                  --returns 1451664000
    select date(-11168899200, 'unixepoch');                     --returns 1616-01-27        
    select time(-11168899200, 'unixepoch');                     --returns 08:00:00

Other stuff:
    select strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', '2012-09-13 12:44:22') --returns 13-09-2012 12:44:22
```

Now, here's an example usage of the above with our Event table:

```
EXAMPLE:
    insert into Event 
        (name, ratingOutOf10, numberOfRatings, category, venue, fromDateTime, description, pricesList, termsAndConditions)
        VALUES
        ('Disco', '3.4', '45', 'Adventure; Music;', 'Bombay Hall', strftime('%s','2016-01-27 20:30:50'), 'A dance party', 'Normal: Rs. 50', 'Items lost will not be the concern of the venue host.');


    insert into Event 
        (name, ratingOutOf10, numberOfRatings, category, venue, fromDateTime, description, pricesList, termsAndConditions)
        VALUES
        ('Trekking', '4.1', '100', 'Outdoors;', 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park', strftime('%s','2016-01-27 08:30'), 'A trek through the wilderness', 'Normal: Rs. 0', 'You must be 18 or more and sign a release.');


    select * from event where fromDateTime > strftime('%s','2016-01-27 20:30:49');
```

I like this solution because it's really easy to work with programming languages, without too much thinking of the various formats involved in SQLite's DATE, TIME, DATETIME, etc. data types.

Answer (score 1):

[`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) always generates four-digit years, so you have to use [`substr`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) to cut off the first two digits:

```
... WHERE RN_CREATE_DATE = strftime('dd-mm-', '2012-07-28 12:04:34') ||
                           substr(strftime('%Y %H:%M:%S', '2012-07-28 12:04:34'), 3)
```

---

It would be easier to store the column values in a format that is directly understood by SQLite.

Comment: if i my RN_CREATE_DATE column value is not in format YY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS and if it is in format dd-mm-YY HH:MM:SS then how will i get the value as per the query

Comment: This query *is* for format `dd-mm-YY HH:MM:SS`. What exactly is your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

`strftime('%Y', '2012-07-28 12:04:34')` returns **2012**, as:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%Y', '2012-07-28 12:04:34');
2012
```

but the RN_CREATE_DATE is of type datetime, which expect a full datetime like '2012-07-28 12:04:34'.  what you want might be simply:

```
SELECT  RN_CREATE_DATE 
FROM DISPOSITION 
WHERE  RN_CREATE_DATE='2012-07-28 12:04:34'
```