# How to parse Date like "Fri Oct 31 14:51:47 جرينتش+03:00 2014"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

SQLLite is giving me a date in this format.

In English language, I am parsing it by using `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

But when I switch the language to Arabic the date I am getting is `Fri Oct 31 14:51:47 جرينتش+03:00 2014`.

How can I parse the Arabic date?

Comment: i think you have to use this format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" instead of considering time zone and try to add your time zone to SimpleDateFormat object later.

Comment: Have you verified that your SimpleDateFormat is using the correct DateFormatSymbols for your Arabic locale? See for example this constructor - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.text.DateFormatSymbols)

Comment: Thanks for your quick sugessions I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Does your sqlite database contain date or a string? If it is date see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406295/how-to-query-in-sqlite-for-different-date-format. You may be limited to the date pattern of the locale (they do vary by locale). If so you could use ICU4J to isolate yourself from locale differences. See http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime.

Comment: I am inserting date as new Date() in DATETIME field of Sqlite. Thats why new Date() is giving me Arabic date in Arabic local and English Date in English Local. What should be the best way to deal with ?

Comment: Need to see more code before recommending a solution. Locales are only applied during formatting or parsing. Date objects are inherently GMT. So where is this formatted date (that needs parsing) coming from? Sqllite query? date.toString()? UI? elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using the fomratter :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, one of many problems with the old java.util.Date/.Calendar/SimpleDateFormat classes. The format you define here is the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I suggest using either Joda-Time or the java.time package built into Java 8. Both libraries use ISO 8601 as their defaults in generating and parsing strings.