# SimpleCursorAdapter/Cursor sqlite3 change datetime format to yyyy/mm/dd?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am trying to change that datetime format that i get from db in sqlite3

```
String[] st1=new String[] {"_id", "DREPORT"};
        int str2[]={ R.id.mainTitle, R.id.textView2};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapterc=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.customlistview,c, st1,str2);
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapterc);
```

the _id (is date) and show as 
[image of listview date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQJ46.jpg)

id like to display it only as mm/dd or yyyy/mm/dd

the query:

```
  public Cursor GetReports(String month)
    {
        String[] n1={"dt AS _id","DREPORT"};
        Cursor c1=db.query(DbHelper.reportt,n1,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        return c1;
    }
```

is there a way to change the query to return other date format ?

or should i just change the filed to String and save it after format change as string 
?

Comment: Dashes are preferred over slashes, then you need no Java code to convert. It's all done via Sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: i tryd to use the DATE() on the datetime field but it didnt work for me, il try agin if i can get it to work this will be the best fix for my problem

Comment: In order to use `DATE()` the data must be in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` (as shown on that page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the _id (is date) and show as yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss....

Well, [SQLite doesn't like that format](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

If possible, you need to reformat the database to hold `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

---

> id like to display it only as mm/dd or yyyy/mm/dd

Once you store as mentioned, you can run `strftime(date_format, timestring)`.

For example,

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%m/%d', datetime('now'));
02/26
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%Y/%m/%d', datetime('now'));
2017/02/26
```

As far as Android goes...

```
String[] n1={"strftime(" + dateFormatToShow + ", dt) AS _id","DREPORT"};
```

Comment: String[] n1={"strftime(" + dateFormatToShow + ", dt) AS _id","DREPORT"}; with  dateFormatToShow = "'%Y/%m/%d'";  this not throwing error but the textview in the listview is empty

Comment: not sure what i did wrong but so far i got nothing il keep trying other formats    String[] n1={"strftime('%Y-%m-%d', dt) AS _id","DREPORT"}; return empty

Comment: works the problem was with how i saved it to the sqlite i did Date().tostring should have done gettime()  , thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date in any format you want using this code

```
public static String formatDateTime(String date, String fromFormat, String toFormat) {
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat, Locale.US).parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat, Locale.US).format(d);
}
```

You just need to pass "date", "fromFormat" (current of the date) and "toFormat" (the format you want).

In your case you can pass 
date: yourDate which you want to format
fromFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
toFromat: "yyyy/MM/dd"

You can use this function to convert any format date to any format you need

Comment: i know how to change a string format the problem is simplecursoradapter takes a cursor object that get created from SQLiteOpenHelper i need a way to change the adapter or the cursor or better yet the query so it return the field in a giving format

Comment: for that you can try query level formatting
SELECT FORMAT(dateColumn ,'YYYY/MM/DD') AS date from myTable or see below answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406295/how-to-query-in-sqlite-for-different-date-format

Comment: i got to run but il giv it a try in the morning reallly hope it works thx :)

Comment: @Arshad `FORMAT(dateColumn ,'YYYY/MM/DD')` is not valid SQLite