# How to deal with non standard date and month format (single digit) in SQLite using strftime?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I have a datetime column in my database like below:

```
12/8/1948 12:00:00 AM
2/19/1952 12:00:00 AM
8/30/1963 12:00:00 AM
9/19/1937 12:00:00 AM
3/4/1955 12:00:00 AM
7/2/1963 12:00:00 AM
5/29/1960 12:00:00 AM
1/9/1958 12:00:00 AM
1/27/1966 12:00:00 AM
```

[image]
[image]

I want to extract the date part using strftime, however, the following expression doesn't work (returns null):

`SELECT strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '5/1/1992 12:00:00 AM')`

I suspect this is due to the fact that the date and month are both 1 digit instead 2 digits, and, there’s AM/PM at the end.

I did check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406295/how-to-query-in-sqlite-for-different-date-format) which is not the same with my case. Thanks in advance for any tip!

Comment: The best thing to do is to always store your dates in ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd`.  You might be looking at some very ugly string manipulations here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tought iso format was `yyyy/mm/dd` ??

Comment: ISO 8601 is yyyy-mm-dd.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You're right :-)

Comment: You already have a datetime in your database or you are trying to insert those string on the db? if you already have those value on db, then the display is based in regional settings. If you are inserting then you should use ISO format instead .

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I already have it as a timestamp field in my db, please see updated image above. Thanks!

Comment: If your table is called `employees`, what is returned by `select('%Y-%m-%d',BirthDate) from employees`?

If that works, your issue is likely that '5/1/1992...' (in your example code) is a string, not a date.

Comment: Then as @BrianDewhirst said, `strftime` should work. The problem is your example you are using a string and the db is trying to convert to timestamp and cant. But in your db they are already timestamp so should work as expected.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza But for some reason, it doesn't...can you check again the new image above?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SQLite has _no_ date time or date column type.  All dates are stored as _text_.  The problem the OP is having is that he is storing his dates in non ISO format I believe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so why the image say `timestamp` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html ... there are no date or timestamp columns to my knowledge